# libvlc-qt realloc error executing example program of libvlc-qt

Tags: c++, qt, vlc

i get the following errors when i try to execute the example of the library Qt-VLC

```
    *** glibc detected *** /home/lalalal/Scrivania/SORGENTI/VLC-QT/build-demo-player-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/src/demo-player: realloc(): invalid pointer: 0xb712ce9c ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb6a6cee2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x25d)[0xb6a7156d]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QListData7reallocEi+0x37)[0xb6d6de67]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QListData6appendEi+0x7c)[0xb6d6df4c]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QListData6appendEv+0x23)[0xb6d6dfd3]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x6c2c8)[0xb6d292c8]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x6a4fd)[0xb6d274fd]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x6b0d8)[0xb6d280d8]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_Z20qMessageFormatString9QtMsgTypeRK18QMessageLogContextRK7QString+0x6cc)[0xb6d288ec]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x6ba72)[0xb6d28a72]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x69227)[0xb6d26227]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x69383)[0xb6d26383]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZNK14QMessageLogger5fatalEPKcz+0x3f)[0xb6d2694f]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QMetaType22registerNormalizedTypeERK10QByteArrayPFvPvEPFS3_PKvES5_PFS3_S3_S7_Ei6QFlagsINS_8TypeFlagEEPK11QMetaObject+0x57f)[0xb6f1c52f]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QMetaType12registerTypeEPKcPFvPvEPFS2_PKvES4_PFS2_S2_S6_Ei6QFlagsINS_8TypeFlagEEPK11QMetaObject+0x67)[0xb6f1c5e7]
/home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QMetaType12registerTypeEPKcPFvPvEPFS2_PKvE+0x57)[0xb6f1c6a7]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(+0x328a8e)[0xaff03a8e]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(+0x126f40)[0xafd01f40]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0xeeab)[0xb77daeab]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0xef94)[0xb77daf94]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0x12fa6)[0xb77defa6]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0xeccf)[0xb77daccf]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0x127f4)[0xb77de7f4]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0xbe9)[0xb5f0bbe9]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0xeccf)[0xb77daccf]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0x133a)[0xb5f0c33a]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(dlopen+0x47)[0xb5f0bc97]
/usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5(+0xb11a0)[0xb5eb41a0]
/usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5(+0x92931)[0xb5e95931]
/usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5(+0x92c78)[0xb5e95c78]
/usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5(+0x92bd3)[0xb5e95bd3]
/usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5(+0x932e2)[0xb5e962e2]
/usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5(+0x9363a)[0xb5e9663a]
/usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5(libvlc_InternalInit+0x163)[0xb5e11a93]
/usr/lib/libvlc.so.5(libvlc_new+0x17b)[0xb69df0cb]
/home/lalalal/libvlc-qt-0.8.1/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt.so.0.8(_ZN11VlcInstanceC1ERK11QStringListP7QObject+0xe3)[0xb7796867]
/home/lalalal/Scrivania/SORGENTI/VLC-QT/build-demo-player-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/src/demo-player[0x804b92d]
/home/lalalal/Scrivania/SORGENTI/VLC-QT/build-demo-player-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/src/demo-player[0x804b692]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb6a104d3]
/home/lalalal/Scrivania/SORGENTI/VLC-QT/build-demo-player-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/src/demo-player[0x804b571]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08050000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 13241347   /home/lalalal/Scrivania/SORGENTI/VLC-QT/build-demo-player-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/src/demo-player
08050000-08051000 r--p 00007000 08:06 13241347   /home/lalalal/Scrivania/SORGENTI/VLC-QT/build-demo-player-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/src/demo-player
08051000-08052000 rw-p 00008000 08:06 13241347   /home/lalalal/Scrivania/SORGENTI/VLC-QT/build-demo-player-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/src/demo-player
0823b000-08551000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
af866000-af8be000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1706455    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6.0.0
af8be000-af8bf000 r--p 00057000 08:06 1706455    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6.0.0
af8bf000-af8c2000 rw-p 00058000 08:06 1706455    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6.0.0
af8c2000-af8d8000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708436    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6.3.0
af8d8000-af8d9000 r--p 00015000 08:06 1708436    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6.3.0
af8d9000-af8da000 rw-p 00016000 08:06 1708436    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6.3.0
af8da000-af8dc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
af8dc000-af8e3000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708477    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6.0.1
af8e3000-af8e4000 r--p 00006000 08:06 1708477    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6.0.1
af8e4000-af8e5000 rw-p 00007000 08:06 1708477    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6.0.1
af8e5000-af8fc000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1704115    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2.4
af8fc000-af8fd000 r--p 00016000 08:06 1704115    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2.4
af8fd000-af8fe000 rw-p 00017000 08:06 1704115    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2.4
af8fe000-afbd2000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1706325    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.1
afbd2000-afbd9000 r--p 002d4000 08:06 1706325    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.1
afbd9000-afbda000 rw-p 002db000 08:06 1706325    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.1
afbda000-afbdb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
afbdb000-b0685000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1706294    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1
b0685000-b06a7000 r--p 00aa9000 08:06 1706294    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1
b06a7000-b06ab000 rw-p 00acb000 08:06 1706294    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1
b06ab000-b06ae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b06ae000-b08c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1846428    /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so
b08c7000-b08d3000 r--p 00219000 08:06 1846428    /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so
b08d3000-b08d5000 rw-p 00225000 08:06 1846428    /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so
b08d5000-b08d6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b08d6000-b09c3000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1706052    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
b09c3000-b09c7000 r--p 000ec000 08:06 1706052    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
b09c7000-b09c8000 rw-p 000f0000 08:06 1706052    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
b09e2000-b0a4f000 r--p 00000000 08:06 3163350    /usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
b0a4f000-b0bb5000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1709061    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.8
b0bb5000-b0bc6000 r--p 00165000 08:06 1709061    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.8
b0bc6000-b0bc7000 rw-p 00176000 08:06 1709061    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.8
b0bc7000-b0c13000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708428    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8.2.0
b0c13000-b0c14000 r--p 0004b000 08:06 1708428    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8.2.0
b0c14000-b0c15000 rw-p 0004c000 08:06 1708428    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8.2.0
b0c15000-b0c81000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1709004    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
b0c81000-b0c82000 r--p 0006c000 08:06 1709004    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
b0c82000-b0c83000 rw-p 0006d000 08:06 1709004    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
b0c83000-b0c87000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b0c87000-b0c8f000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 9700269    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0.7.6
b0c8f000-b0c90000 r--p 00007000 08:06 9700269    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0.7.6
b0c90000-b0c91000 rw-p 00008000 08:06 9700269    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0.7.6
b0c91000-b0cf4000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1706259    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulsecommon-1.1.so
b0cf4000-b0cf5000 r--p 00062000 08:06 1706259    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulsecommon-1.1.so
b0cf5000-b0cf6000 rw-p 00063000 08:06 1706259    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulsecommon-1.1.so
b0cf6000-b0d42000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1706258    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.13.5
b0d42000-b0d43000 r--p 0004b000 08:06 1706258    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.13.5
b0d43000-b0d44000 rw-p 0004c000 08:06 1706258    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.13.5
b0d57000-b0d5c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1846120    /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/audio_output/libalsa_plugin.so
b0d5c000-b0d5d000 r--p 00004000 08:06 1846120    /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/audio_output/libalsa_plugin.so
b0d5d000-b0d5e000 rw-p 00005000 08:06 1846120    /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/audio_output/libalsa_plugin.so
b0d5e000-b0db5000 r--p 00000000 08:06 2493685    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf
b0db5000-b0dca000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1707707    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
b0dca000-b0dcb000 r--p 00014000 08:06 1707707    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
b0dcb000-b0dcc000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 1707707    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
b0dcc000-b0df5000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1704395    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
b0df5000-b0df6000 r--p 00028000 08:06 1704395    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
b0df6000-b0df7000 rw-p 00029000 08:06 1704395    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
b0df7000-b0e3b000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708824    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.0.401.0
b0e3b000-b0e3c000 r--p 00043000 08:06 1708824    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.0.401.0
b0e3c000-b0e3d000 rw-p 00044000 08:06 1708824    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.0.401.0
b0e42000-b0e47000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708544    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
b0e47000-b0e48000 r--p 00004000 08:06 1708544    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
b0e48000-b0e49000 rw-p 00005000 08:06 1708544    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
b0e49000-b0e4f000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708843    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjson.so.0.0.1
b0e4f000-b0e50000 r--p 00005000 08:06 1708843    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjson.so.0.0.1
b0e50000-b0e51000 rw-p 00006000 08:06 1708843    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjson.so.0.0.1
b0e51000-b0e55000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 9700267    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
b0e55000-b0e56000 r--p 00003000 08:06 9700267    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
b0e56000-b0e57000 rw-p 00004000 08:06 9700267    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
b0e57000-b0ea9000 r--p 00000000 08:06 2493656    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
b0ea9000-b0f00000 r--p 00000000 08:06 2493685    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf
b0f00000-b0f21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b0f21000-b1000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b1004000-b1012000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 9699549    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0
b1012000-b1013000 r--p 0000e000 08:06 9699549    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0
b1013000-b1014000 rw-p 0000f000 08:06 9699549    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0
b1014000-b101a000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1709577    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so
b101a000-b101b000 r--p 00005000 08:06 1709577    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so
b101b000-b101c000 rw-p 00006000 08:06 1709577    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so
b101c000-b101e000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1709783    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
b101e000-b101f000 r--p 00001000 08:06 1709783    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
b101f000-b1020000 rw-p 00002000 08:06 1709783    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
b1020000-b1021000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362260    /var/cache/fontconfig/c05880de57d1f5e948fdfacc138775d9-le32d4.cache-3
b1021000-b1027000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362255    /var/cache/fontconfig/945677eb7aeaf62f1d50efc3fb3ec7d8-le32d4.cache-3
b1027000-b1029000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362256    /var/cache/fontconfig/99e8ed0e538f840c565b6ed5dad60d56-le32d4.cache-3
b1029000-b102c000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362242    /var/cache/fontconfig/2cd17615ca594fa2959ae173292e504c-le32d4.cache-3
b102c000-b102d000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362267    /var/cache/fontconfig/e7071f4a29fa870f4323321c154eba04-le32d4.cache-3
b102d000-b102e000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362240    /var/cache/fontconfig/0d8c3b2ac0904cb8a57a757ad11a4a08-le32d4.cache-3
b102e000-b1032000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362257    /var/cache/fontconfig/a755afe4a08bf5b97852ceb7400b47bc-le32d4.cache-3
b1032000-b103d000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362239    /var/cache/fontconfig/04aabc0a78ac019cf9454389977116d2-le32d4.cache-3
b103d000-b103e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b103e000-b183e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2373]
b183e000-b1858000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1706000    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-glib.so.4.0.13
b1858000-b1859000 r--p 00019000 08:06 1706000    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-glib.so.4.0.13
b1859000-b185a000 rw-p 0001a000 08:06 1706000    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-glib.so.4.0.13
b185a000-b186b000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1705996    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-gtk.so.4.0.13
b186b000-b186c000 r--p 00010000 08:06 1705996    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-gtk.so.4.0.13
b186c000-b186d000 rw-p 00011000 08:06 1705996    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-gtk.so.4.0.13
b1870000-b1877000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2367397    /var/cache/fontconfig/6d41288fd70b0be22e8c3a91e032eec0-le32d4.cache-3
b1877000-b187a000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362245    /var/cache/fontconfig/385c0604a188198f04d133e54aba7fe7-le32d4.cache-3
b187a000-b1887000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362263    /var/cache/fontconfig/d52a8644073d54c13679302ca1180695-le32d4.cache-3
b1887000-b188a000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 9700187    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
b188a000-b188b000 r--p 00002000 08:06 9700187    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
b188b000-b188c000 rw-p 00003000 08:06 9700187    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
b188c000-b189c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708915    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
b189c000-b189d000 r--p 0000f000 08:06 1708915    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
b189d000-b189e000 rw-p 00010000 08:06 1708915    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
b189e000-b1920000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 9699547    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
b1920000-b1921000 r--p 00081000 08:06 9699547    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
b1921000-b1923000 rw-p 00082000 08:06 9699547    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
b1923000-b1933000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1709032    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.12
b1933000-b1934000 r--p 0000f000 08:06 1709032    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.12
b1934000-b1935000 rw-p 00010000 08:06 1709032    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.12
b1935000-b19f4000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1717620    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.21.8
b19f4000-b19f8000 r--p 000bf000 08:06 1717620    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.21.8
b19f8000-b19f9000 rw-p 000c3000 08:06 1717620    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.21.8
b19f9000-b1a1d000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1704117    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.2.2
b1a1d000-b1a1e000 r--p 00023000 08:06 1704117    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.2.2
b1a1e000-b1a1f000 rw-p 00024000 08:06 1704117    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.2.2
b1a1f000-b1b66000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1706050    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
b1b66000-b1b6a000 r--p 00147000 08:06 1706050    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
b1b6a000-b1b6b000 rw-p 0014b000 08:06 1706050    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
b1b6b000-b1b6c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b1b6c000-b1b98000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708695    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5
b1b98000-b1b99000 r--p 0002b000 08:06 1708695    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5
b1b99000-b1b9a000 rw-p 0002c000 08:06 1708695    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5
b1b9a000-b1bfc000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1724530    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnomevfs-2.so.0.2400.4
b1bfc000-b1bfe000 r--p 00061000 08:06 1724530    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnomevfs-2.so.0.2400.4
b1bfe000-b1c00000 rw-p 00063000 08:06 1724530    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnomevfs-2.so.0.2400.4
b1c00000-b1c21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b1c21000-b1d00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b1d01000-b1d02000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2361926    /var/cache/fontconfig/4794a0821666d79190d59a36cb4f44b5-le32d4.cache-3
b1d02000-b1d05000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362254    /var/cache/fontconfig/8801497958630a81b71ace7c5f9b32a8-le32d4.cache-3
b1d05000-b1d15000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708554    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3.2.9
b1d15000-b1d16000 r--p 0000f000 08:06 1708554    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3.2.9
b1d16000-b1d17000 rw-p 00010000 08:06 1708554    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3.2.9
b1d17000-b1d23000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708556    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3.5.3
b1d23000-b1d24000 r--p 0000b000 08:06 1708556    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3.5.3
b1d24000-b1d25000 rw-p 0000c000 08:06 1708556    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3.5.3
b1d25000-b1d4e000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1709059    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.5
b1d4e000-b1d4f000 r--p 00028000 08:06 1709059    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.5
b1d4f000-b1d50000 rw-p 00029000 08:06 1709059    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.5
b1d50000-b1d58000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708866    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.0
b1d58000-b1d59000 r--p 00008000 08:06 1708866    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.0
b1d59000-b1d5a000 rw-p 00009000 08:06 1708866    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.0
b1d5a000-b1d6b000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1709034    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1.2.9
b1d6b000-b1d6c000 r--p 00010000 08:06 1709034    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1.2.9
b1d6c000-b1d6d000 rw-p 00011000 08:06 1709034    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1.2.9
b1d6d000-b1d7c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708592    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5
b1d7c000-b1d7d000 r--p 0000e000 08:06 1708592    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5
b1d7d000-b1d7e000 rw-p 0000f000 08:06 1708592    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5
b1d7e000-b1d82000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1708588    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcanberra-gtk.so.0.1.8
b1d82000-b1d83000 r--p 00003000 08:06 1708588    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcanberra-gtk.so.0.1.8
b1d83000-b1d84000 rw-p 00004000 08:06 1708588    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcanberra-gtk.so.0.1.8
b1d85000-b1d89000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362243    /var/cache/fontconfig/3047814df9a2f067bd2d96a2b9c36e5a-le32d4.cache-3
b1d89000-b1d8a000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362248    /var/cache/fontconfig/56cf4f4769d0f4abc89a4895d7bd3ae1-le32d4.cache-3
b1d8a000-b1d8b000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362259    /var/cache/fontconfig/b9d506c9ac06c20b433354fa67a72993-le32d4.cache-3
b1d8b000-b1d8f000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362258    /var/cache/fontconfig/b47c4e1ecd0709278f4910c18777a504-le32d4.cache-3
b1d8f000-b1d91000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362392    /var/cache/fontconfig/e13b20fdb08344e0e664864cc2ede53d-le32d4.cache-3
b1d91000-b1d94000 r--s 00000000 08:06 2362351    /var/cache/fontconfig/7ef2298fde41cc6eeb7af42e48b7d293-le32d4.cache-3
b1d94000-b1d99000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1709586    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
b1d99000-b1d9a000 r--p 00004000 08:06 1709586    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
b1d9a000-b1d9b000 rw-p 00005000 08:06 1709586    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
b1d9b000-b1d9e000 r--p 00000000 08:06 4332053    /usr/share/locale-langpack/it/LC_MESSAGES/atk10.mo
b1d9e000-b1dd3000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1709570    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libmurrine.so
b1dd3000-b1dd4000 r--p 00034000 08:06 1709570    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libmurrine.so
b1dd4000-b1dd5000 rw-p 00035000 08:06 1709570    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libmurrine.so

    ...other libraries...

b7126000-b7127000 ---p 00469000 08:06 529988     /home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.1.1
b7127000-b712c000 r--p 00469000 08:06 529988     /home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.1.1
b712c000-b713f000 rw-p 0046e000 08:06 529988     /home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.1.1
b713f000-b7140000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7140000-b773f000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 530036     /home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.1.1
b773f000-b7754000 r--p 005fe000 08:06 530036     /home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.1.1
b7754000-b776c000 rw-p 00613000 08:06 530036     /home/lalalal/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.1.1
b776c000-b7784000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 13241321   /home/lalalal/libvlc-qt-0.8.1/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt-widgets.so.0.8.1
b7784000-b7785000 r--p 00018000 08:06 13241321   /home/lalalal/libvlc-qt-0.8.1/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt-widgets.so.0.8.1
b7785000-b7786000 rw-p 00019000 08:06 13241321   /home/lalalal/libvlc-qt-0.8.1/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt-widgets.so.0.8.1
b7786000-b7787000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7787000-b77c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 13241237   /home/lalalal/libvlc-qt-0.8.1/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt.so.0.8.1
b77c7000-b77c8000 r--p 0003f000 08:06 13241237   /home/lalalal/libvlc-qt-0.8.1/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt.so.0.8.1
b77c8000-b77c9000 rw-p 00040000 08:06 13241237   /home/lalalal/libvlc-qt-0.8.1/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt.so.0.8.1
b77c9000-b77cb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77cb000-b77cc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b77cc000-b77ec000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 9699459    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b77ec000-b77ed000 r--p 0001f000 08:06 9699459    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b77ed000-b77ee000 rw-p 00020000 08:06 9699459    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
bfba6000-bfbc7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

if i get the backtrace, this is the result:

```
~"#0  0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()\n"
    >~"#1  0xb72371df in __GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64\n"
    >~"#2  0xb723a825 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:91\n"
    >~"#3  0xb727439a in __libc_message (do_abort=2, fmt=0xb736eaa8 \"*** glibc detected *** %s: %s: 0x%s ***\\n\") at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:201\n"
    >~"#4  0xb727eee2 in malloc_printerr (action=, str=, ptr=0xb793ee9c) at malloc.c:5018\n"
    >~"#5  0xb728356d in __GI___libc_realloc (oldmem=0xb793ee9c, bytes=32) at malloc.c:3021\n"
    >~"#6  0xb757fe67 in QListData::realloc(int) () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#7  0xb757ff4c in QListData::append(int) () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#8  0xb757ffd3 in QListData::append() () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#9  0xb753b2c8 in ?? () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#10 0xb75394fd in ?? () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#11 0xb753a0d8 in ?? () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#12 0xb753a8ec in qMessageFormatString(QtMsgType, QMessageLogContext const&, QString const&) () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#13 0xb753aa72 in ?? () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#14 0xb7538227 in ?? () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#15 0xb7538383 in ?? () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#16 0xb753894f in QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#17 0xb772e52f in QMetaType::registerNormalizedType(QByteArray const&, void (*)(void*), void* (*)(void const*), void (*)(void*), void* (*)(void*, void const*), int, QFlags, QMetaObject const*) () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#18 0xb772e5e7 in QMetaType::registerType(char const*, void (*)(void*), void* (*)(void const*), void (*)(void*), void* (*)(void*, void const*), int, QFlags, QMetaObject const*) () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#19 0xb772e6a7 in QMetaType::registerType(char const*, void (*)(void*), void* (*)(void const*)) () from /home/bertero/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
    >~"#20 0xb071fa8e in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4\n"
    >~"#21 0xb051df40 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4\n"
    >~"#22 0xb7feceab in call_init (env=0xbffff75c, argv=0xbffff754, argc=1, l=) at dl-init.c:85\n"
    >~"#23 call_init (l=, argc=1, argv=0xbffff754, env=0xbffff75c) at dl-init.c:35\n"
    >~"#24 0xb7fecf94 in _dl_init (main_map=, argc=1, argv=0xbffff754, env=0xbffff75c) at dl-init.c:134\n"
    >~"#25 0xb7ff0fa6 in dl_open_worker (a=0xbfffee20) at dl-open.c:549\n"
    >~"#26 0xb7fecccf in _dl_catch_error (objname=0xbfffee44, errstring=0xbfffee48, mallocedp=0xbfffee4f, operate=0xb7ff0c40 , args=0xbfffee20) at dl-error.c:178\n"
    >~"#27 0xb7ff07f4 in _dl_open (file=0x834ab78 \"/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so\", mode=-2147483647, caller_dlopen=0xb66c61a0, nsid=-2, argc=1, argv=0xbffff754, env=0xbffff75c) at dl-open.c:639\n"
    >~"#28 0xb671dbe9 in dlopen_doit (a=0xbfffeff0) at dlopen.c:67\n"
    >~"#29 0xb7fecccf in _dl_catch_error (objname=0x8053454, errstring=0x8053458, mallocedp=0x8053450, operate=0xb671db50 , args=0xbfffeff0) at dl-error.c:178\n"
    >~"#30 0xb671e33a in _dlerror_run (operate=0xb671db50 , args=0xbfffeff0) at dlerror.c:164\n"
    >~"#31 0xb671dc97 in __dlopen (file=0x834ab78 \"/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so\", mode=1) at dlopen.c:88\n"
    >~"#32 0xb66c61a0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5\n"
    >~"#33 0xb66a7931 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5\n"
    >~"#34 0xb66a7c78 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5\n"
    >~"#35 0xb66a7bd3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5\n"
    >~"#36 0xb66a82e2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5\n"
    >~"#37 0xb66a863a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5\n"
    >~"#38 0xb6623a93 in libvlc_InternalInit () from /usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5\n"
    >~"#39 0xb71f10cb in libvlc_new () from /usr/lib/libvlc.so.5\n"
    >~"#40 0xb7fa8867 in VlcInstance::VlcInstance(QStringList const&, QObject*) () from /home/bertero/libvlc-qt-0.8.1/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt.so.0.8\n"
    >~"#41 0x0804b92d in DemoPlayer::DemoPlayer (this=0xbffff67c, parent=0x0) at ../../demo-player/src/DemoPlayer.cpp:35\n"
    >~"#42 0x0804b692 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff754) at ../../demo-player/src/main.cpp:34\n"
```

how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same SIGABRT trying to run a program with Qt.

Turns out the problem was because I had linked my program to qt5, but libvlc tried to load the qt4 plugin which I believe is why the crashes occurred.
(See the line containing /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so in the stacktrace)

The way I solved it was by "disabling" that plugin for libvlc, which can be done for example by renaming the file to a different file ending.